# Firebase / AngularFire5 : Query null property

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, angularfire

I have data in my `Firebase` where the property `stuffCategory` on each stored item in a collection can be a value or is never set. I am trying to query the items where `stuffCategory` is null (i.e not set to a value). Aside from perhaps having to set  a placeholder value and query against that, is there a way to achieve this with `angularfire`?

```
  this.angularFire.database
          .list(`accounts/${this.stuffKey}/stuff`,{ 
            query:{
            orderByChild:"stuffCategory",
            equalTo:null
          }
          })
          .subscribe((stuff: any[]) => {
            console.log(stuff);
         )}, (err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
      }
    }
```

Comment: try this `{ query: { orderByChild: 'stuffCategory', startAt: false })`

Comment: @santoshsingh No luck, setting `startAt` to either `true` or `false` returns the items that contain `stuffCategory` in both circumstances. 'm trying to get the items that do not contain `stuffCategory`

Comment: try this `equalTo:undefined`